# How to get the accuracy of an evaluation object in weka java?

Tags: java, weka, cross-validation, evaluation

I am using weka with java for classification purposes, I did manually the cross validation and I would like to know if there is a way to get the accuracy of an evaluation object i don't want the whole metrics like:

```
 System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("=== " + folds + "-fold Cross-validation ===", false));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the accuracy you just have to use the function pctCorrect(), which gives you the percentage of instances correctly classified by your model.

`double accuracy = eval.pctCorrect();
 System.out.println("Accuracy = " + accuracy);`